# Flex grid to move last flex-item to the right

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div, containing 3 children, i want to show them beside each other, except for the last div `class="form-message"` to be in a new line but to the right, under the div `class="form-field"`, how can this be done?

```css
.form-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.form-row .form-label {
  width: 35%;
}

.form-row .form-field {
  width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <label class="form-label">Your message</label>
  <div class="form-field">
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-message">
    <p>You can write your message here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added colors to help you understanding whats going on: https://jsfiddle.net/erhuftqd/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use same with for `.form-field` and `.form-message`  and `justify-content: flex-end;` for `.form-row`

```css
.form-row {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: flex-end;
}
.form-label {
  width: 35%;
}
.form-field, .form-message {
  width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
   <label class="form-label">Your message</label>
   <div class="form-field">
       <textarea name="message"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="form-message">
      <p>You can write your message here</p>
   </div>
</div>
```